# Error en contador usando Python

Tags: python, mysql

Estoy listando unos cursos desde una BDD usando mysql, con este codigo

```
def listaCursos(cursos):
    print("cursos: ")
    for curso in cursos:
        contador = 1
        datos = "{0}. codigo {1}. Nombre: {2} {3}"
        print(datos.format(contador ,curso[0], curso[1], curso[2]))
        contador = contador +1
    print( " ")
```

sin embargo cuando lo ejecuto el contador no incrementa si no se queda en 1. por que sera?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que declarar el contador antes (fuera) del for. Si no, en cada iteracción del bucle va a asignarle el valor de 1.

Salu2

Comment: Tu respuesta esta perfecta, tal vez si agregaras un poco de código del cómo quedaría se vería un poco más completa. ;)

Comment: gracias! @catraba

Answer (score 1):

Puse el contador fuera del for

```
def listaCursos(cursos):
print("cursos: ")
contador = 1
for curso in cursos:
   
    datos = "{0}. codigo {1}. Nombre: {2} {3}"
    print(datos.format(contador ,curso[0], curso[1], curso[2]))
    contador = contador +1
print( " ")
```

Comment: Cuando haces respuestas, no solo piensas en solucionar el problema, si no que también piensas en que el lector entienda por que la solución funciona. Estaría bueno que edites la respuesta y des alguna explicación de por que tu solución funciona, mejorando así tu respuesta c: